# Gfortran: error trying to exec 'f951': execvp

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I just reinstalled my gfortran after upgrading(?) my computer to Mountain Lion. However, even though the command "gfortran -v" definitely shows that it is installed, whenever I try to compile a program, I get the following error message:

```
i686-apple-darwin10-gfortran-4.2.1: error trying to exec 'f951': execvp: No such file or directory
```

How can this be fixed? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I found the answer in the comments [here](http://eftrunk.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-fix-error-trying-to-exec-f951.html). Basically, remove your old Fortran from /usr/bin/, then reinstall from [Sourceforge.](http://hpc.sourceforge.net)